# Profinite closure of characteristic subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $F$ be a free group of finite rank, and $K\subset F$ a finite index characteristic subgroup.

Let $\hat{F}$ be the profinite completion of $F$ (i.e. a free profinite group of same rank), and $\bar{K}$ the closure of $K$ in $\hat{F}$.

What are necessary and/or sufficient conditions for $\bar{K}$ to be characteristic in  $\hat{F}$?

Is there an example of such $K$ for which $\bar{K}$ is not characteristic?

**Motivation:** I'm trying to answer the question whether there exists a finite 
 (non-abelian) *simple* characteristic quotient of $F$. This will be possible only with a characteristic subgroup whose profinite closure is *not* characteristic.

This question was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250809/when-does-a-characteristic-subgroup-remain-characteristic-in-the-profinite-compl) in a more general setting. A sufficient condition was given in the answer, namely that $K$ be "hyper-characteristic" (or "isomorph-free"). However this doesn't help me, as the quotient by such a subgroup cannot be a non-abeian simple group, so I'm looking for other conditions.

Comment: *"(i.e., a free profinite group of the same rank)"* The profinite completion is not just a profinite group, it's a profinite group along with a homomorphism from the original group.

Comment: The first question is precisely a duplicate of the linked question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250809/) by @rtz. It's a pity that rtz accepted his/her own answer, because it would be better gather new answers there, and because it would be worth isolating the second question (about existence of an example).

Comment: @YCor The linked question considered general $F$, I was hoping that restricting to free $F$ might help to gather new answers.

Comment: The other point is that finding an example can be quite energy-consuming (unless there's a pointer to the literature, or a simple example I would fail to see), so it would be more motivating if it's part of a single question.

Comment: Here is something in answe to myself. I'm not 100% sure it's correct, and I don't know yet if it can be used to find concrete examples. Let $K_{n}$ be the intersection of all normal subgroups of $F$ of index $n$. Then $\hat{F}$ is the inverse limit of $F/K_{n}$, and the automorphism group of $\hat{F}$ is the inverse limit of automorphism groups of these quotients. Hence thw closure of  $H\subset F$ is characteristic in $\hat{F}$ iff the image of $H$ is characteristic in $F/K_{n}$ for every $n$,